# What is the result of this C# Bitwise-OR?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, enums, bitwise-or

I am trying to check permissions for SharePoint users in c# and I came across the following code that seems to work:

```
isGranted = spweb.DoesUserHavePermissions(userlogin, SPBasePermissions.EmptyMask | SPBasePermissions.ViewPages);
```

The first argument is the user to check a permission of. The second argument is the permission to check if the user has.

My question is, what is the result of the bitwise-or between emptymask and viewpages permissions? What permission is this actually checking against?

Comment: See this question for details of enum bitwise operations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285986/flags-enum-bitwise-operations-vs-string-of-bits

Comment: The easiest way would be to cast the values to their underlying type and find out yourself. *Guessing* by the name, `EmptyMask` is probably `0` and doesn't really do anything here, but I might be completely wrong...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `EmptyMask` [is defined as zero](http://hristopavlov.wordpress.com/2008/09/18/implementing-custom-security-rights-in-sharepoint/), the result is the same as passing the `SPBasePermissions.ViewPages` with no `EmptyMask`:

```
[Flags]
public enum SPBasePermissions
{
    EmptyMask =                 0×0000000000000000,
    ...
}
```

Comment: I guess the clue was in the name. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's checking against both permissions. The permissions are bitwise flags.

I don't know the actual values, but say Empty Mask is: 01000000, and ViewPage is 00100000 - then OR'ing them would be 01100000 - so you get both of them together.

So then if you want to check that a user has the ViewPage permission, you can take the OR'ed value, AND it against the value for ViewPage, and if it's > 0 then you know you have permission.

Answer (score 1):

The enumeration has the `Flag` attribute, which indicates you can combine values using bitwise operators.

Actually, this makes no sense to combine `EmptyMask` (which is 0) with another value, as `0 | X` is always equal to `X`. Just use the other value.